# Reading an Access Query from Visual Studio 2010 (VB.NET)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I have a database in access and one of the fields is 'Is Quick'. I have a query that filters all of these out. How would I get the data from that query in Visual Studio 2010 (Express). VB code please.

Answer (score 0):

See *How to connect to a database and run a command by using ADO.NET and Visual Basic .NET* at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301075.

In your specific case you want to use the OleDB classes in the `OleDb` namespace.

- MSDN Search for *access oledb query vb.net* at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?Refinement=-112%2c108&Query=access+oledb+query+vb.net